# Undefined offset error, but the offset exists

Tags: php, sql

I want to make a list of all my users, so I used the following SQL query:

```
"SELECT Username FROM inloggen"
```

which works perfectly fine when I run it in phpMyAdmin and when I use

```
$list = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM inloggen")); in php,
```

`echo "<p> $list[0] </p>";` correctly returns the first user, but `echo "<p> $list[1] </p>";` and higher all return an Undefined offset error, even though I have 6 users in my database.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Don't nest your mysql functions like that

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() returns 1 row from the database, not all of them; you need to do mysql_fetch_array() for each row until it returns false

Comment: Iterate over it. `while($result == mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT username from inloggen"))){ //access columns here }` But more importantly and before you go any further, please change to `mysqli_` or `pdo` as the `mysql` extension is deprecated and in `php 5.5+` it is removed.

Comment: You appear to be *learning* the legacy MySQL extension. I hope you understand it's the equivalent of learning Latin—it's okay if you're going to work with PHP code found in ruined abbeys and the like.